# Validar sem dar post com html helper asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Como faço para validar usando Html helper e data annotation, mas sem dar post

Ou seja, ex:

StringLength(10) 
Enquanto ele está digitando, ir validando essa anotation...(entre outras)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não se esqueça de adicionar a qual `Model` a `View` se refere: `@model Dominio.Categoria`

```
[View]
@model Dominio.Categoria

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome)<br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome)
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
    </div>
}
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

No `BundleConfig` você precisa adicionar o seguinte `Bundle`:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
       "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
       "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Comment: Essa validação, ocorre apenas ao enviar o post, usando isValid no controller

Comment: Essa validação é para acontecer em tempo real, usando o Bundle

Comment: A resposta do Diego está correta Rod! A validação unobtrusive é feita via javascript, ele somente da o POST se a validação unobtrusive passar! Se isso não estiver ocorrendo verifique o seu web.config e tenha certeza que essas 2 chaves estão ativadas:
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />